# How can I create pentagon and octagon grids in android

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

[pentagon and octagon in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lhjO.png)

I want to create pentagon and octagon grid ui in  android as shown in the photo. Is there any library or resource I can use or refer to? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this xml:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="628.0"
    android:viewportWidth="726.0" android:width="27dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
        android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use shapes to create any kind of shape but with bit complexity. So try not make any complex shapes which will cause you rendering problems.